# Как реализовать динамическую подгрузку меток в гугл карте?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, карты

Изначально на странице выводится определенное количество меток. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при определенных событиях, например, масштабирование, все загруженные ранее метки убирать и подгружать с сервера новые.

Comment: В чем именно у вас возникла проблема: в подписке на события карты, в создании меток или в загрузке данных?

Comment: Вот есть функция:

Comment: Есть у меня функция, она добавляет метки, кластеризует их. Эта функция подгружает данные с сервера после чего наносит метки на карту. Когда пользователь, например, воспользуется фильтром, мне нанесенные ранее метки нужно убрать, и вызвать опять эту функцию(сервер уже отдаст информацию с учетем фильтра)

Comment: По-моему у вас есть полное понимание того, что нужно делать, попробуйте реализовать задуманное, если что-то будет не получаться, то справшивайте.